# Not able to use two models in the same django view

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to django, and can't seem to make two models in the same view work. I have tried the guide in the djano docs, but can't seem to be able to use two different models templates in the html. Is it possible that i've misunderstood how the OneToOneField works?

The html just renders an empty div. The account templates works fine.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import template
import phonenumbers

# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(('all', 'all'), ('danielk', 'danielk')), blank=True)
    phoneNumber = models.IntegerField()
    birthDate = models.DateField()
    streetAdress = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def formatedPhone(self, country=None):
        return phonenumbers.parse(Account.phoneNumber, "NO")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("account-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Account meta"
        verbose_name_plural = "Accounts meta"

class Notes(models.Model):
    userNoted = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField((""), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("note-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Note detial"
        verbose_name_plural = "Notes details"
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import *


# Create your views here.

from .models import *

#Users
class echoUsersOverview(generic.ListView):
    model = Account
    template_name = "echo/users/echo-users-overview.html"

class echoUsersDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Account
    template_name = "echo/users/echo-users-detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Account notes'] = Notes.objects.all()
        return context
```

Html

```
<div class="notification is-warning">
                    {{ notes.note }}
                </div>
                <nav class="panel">
                    <p class="panel-heading">
                        User information
                    </p>
                    <label class="panel-block is-paddingless">
                        <table class="table is-fullwidth">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 150px;"><strong>Group</strong></td>
                                    <td>Super Administrator</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Site manager</strong></td>
                                    <td>
                                    {% if account.site == 'all' %}
                                        <span class="tag is-danger">{{account.site}}</span>
                                    {% elif  account.site == 'danielk' %}
                                        <span class="tag is-info">{{account.site}}</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
                                    <td>{{account.id}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Birthdate</strong></td>
                                    <td>{{account.birthDate}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Phonenumber</strong></td>
                                    <td><a href="tel:{{account.phoneNumber}}">{{account.phoneNumber}}<a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                                    <td><a href="mailto:{{account.user.email}}">{{account.user.email}}</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Streetadress</strong></td>
                                    <td>{{account.streetAdress}}
                                        <br>{{account.zipCode}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </label>

                    </nav>
```

Comment: I think you're confused over your variable names. You've added the `Notes` data to your template using the key `Account notes`, yet apparently tried to reference it as `notes.note`. You should use the key `notes` - although this still won't work as it is,  because the value is an entire queryset (an object representing multiple rows of data), so you'll have to loop through it in the template and extract the `note` property from each individual entry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @RobinZigmond. I have replaced ['Account notes'] with ['notes'], and done a for loop like {% for notes in notes_list %} {{ notes.note }} {% endfor %} in the html, but still cant seem to get it to work. Am i still missing something? Sorry to bother you, as i said, im quite new to django

Comment: you've now got a new discrepancy in names. Try using `notes_list` as the context variable name, and leave the template untouched. (Problem is that you're referring to it in the template as `notes_list` but have used the key `notes`.)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, you don't need to pass `Notes` model instances to context, if you want to access the user's note only. You can simply do it by:

```
<div class="notification is-warning">
     {{ object.user.notes }}
</div>
```

Please check the [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) documentation regarding this.